# If submanifold $P$ is geodesically complete then $P=M$, for connected $M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Let $P$ be an open submanifold of a semi-Riemannian manifold $M$. If $P$ is geodesically complete and $M$ is connected then $P=M$.

My attempted proof:

Define the following metric on $M$, $d(x,y)=\inf\{L(\gamma):\text{smallest lenght}\}$

Let $t_n$ define a cauchy sequnce  in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for $m,n>N$, for $\epsilon>0$

$|t_n-t_m|<\epsilon$

Then:

$$d(\gamma(t_n),\gamma(t_m))\leqslant|t_n-t_m|<\epsilon$$

so that $\gamma(t_n)$ deintes a cauchy sequnce in $P$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n=t$, because $P$ is geodesically complete then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma(t_n)=\gamma(t)$$

where $\gamma(t)\in P$

Hence, $P$ is complete. Once it is complete, it must be closed in the subset topology in $M$. However, by hypothesis it is open. Since $M$ is connected either $P=\emptyset$ or $P=M$.
Since $P\neq\emptyset$, then $P=M$.

**Question**:

Is this the correct approach? Or is there a way to do it without exploring the metric properties of the manifold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you use that $P$ is open to show that $P$ is closed? If not, there are examples of complete not closed submanifold [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349159/example-of-complete-but-not-closed-riemannian-submanifold)

Comment: Your attempted proof fails already in the first sentence since $M$ is only a semi-Riemannian manifold and for non-Riemannian $M$ you will never get a metric this way. You cannot use metric completeness (unless $M$ is Riemannian), you have to appeal to the geodesic completeness.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes I did it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So how would you prove it? Can you show?

Comment: Please do not (delete and) [repost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/can-i-ask-the-same-question-twice) an [identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699606). Instead, edit your old post to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why did people vote to close it?

Comment: I cannot speak for other downvoters but I already commented your old post. The reason is that it was a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq). What you should do to retrieve from such a situation is not delete and repost, but edit your post with some real attempt(s) and vote for reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps of the proof.

1. Assume that $P\ne M$ and let $x\in M\setminus P$ be a boundary point of $P$ in $M$.
2. Pick a point $y\in P$ such that there exists a geodesic $\gamma: [0,1]\to M$ connecting $y$ to $x$. (You should figure out why does such $y$ exists.)
3. Consider a maximal open interval $I\subset [0,1]$ such that $\gamma(I)\subset P$. Using geodesic completeness of $P$ conclude that the boundary points of $I$ are mapped by $\gamma$ to $P$.
4. Obtain a contradiction with $x\notin P$ and finish the proof.

Comment: How do you obtain the contradiction $x\notin P$, by using the geodesic completeness of P?

Comment: Did you already finish steps 1--3?

Comment: I have no idea how to finish those.

Comment: Then start with Step 1 (prove that such $x$ exists).

Comment: Step 1 is just the definition of $x$ as a boundary point.

Comment: No, it is not. You have to show that there exists such $x$. It is not hard at all but you just said that you have no idea how to finish this step. Once you are done with 1, verify 2.

Comment: How did you use point $y$?

Comment: If you do not have $y$, you do not have $\gamma$.

Comment: With just these points I do not understand how the proof would be written. I am still new to this topic.